# keeping all modules route configuration in one js file is good practice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

In AngularJs, I wanted to know is keeping all modules route configuration in one single config.js file is good practice or not.

If no why please explain.

Regards,
nG

Comment: Depends on the size, complexity of your app.
If it's a small app, its OK to use, however in case of large apps, it's better to split the routes depending on your modules.

Comment: As of now my app is having 4 modules and each module have a view associated. If we choose not to load a particular module then keeping all route configurations in a single file requires people to remember the file and update the same. if I choose not to keep then its just a module removal or insertion to main module. right?

Comment: Yes. If you have 4 modules, it's better to have separate files for each module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bad practice.

I prefer to structure files per feature (for each feature I have a module). And your main app depends of these modules.
In module for a feature I have - definition of module, controllers, services, directives (views sometimes), configuration (if needed) and routes. If I have more than one controller (or service, directive etc), I create a module for these.
I've tried other approaches (e.g. grouping by function - controllers, services etc), but this approach is the best. 
Btw, If you're working in team, this approach is the most correct.

I know that routes for authentication are in authentication module, but not in the file that contains ALL routes (and can have a hundred of lines).

Example of project structure that I use:

```
app
├── alerts
│   ├── alerts.controller.js
│   ├── alerts.interceptor.service.js
│   ├── alerts.module.js
│   └── alerts.service.js
├── auth
│   ├── auth.module.js
│   ├── auth.routes.js
│   ├── auth.service.js
│   ├── controllers.module.js
│   ├── directives.module.js
│   ├── emailValidator.directive.js
│   ├── login.controller.js
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── loginMenu.controller.js
│   ├── pwdStrength.directive.js
│   ├── register.controller.js
│   ├── register.html
│   └── usernameValidator.directive.js
├── app.config.js
├── app.interceptor.js
├── app.module.js
├── app.routes.js
└── index.html
```